# Add Figures in Appendix as well as in Thesis

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, appendices

I have a number of scatterplots that I want to add in the appendix, in landscapemode, to give a better resolution than in the main part of my thesis.

Is there some clever way to do that, so the reader easily can find them? For example add a new `ToC` and `list of figures` for the appendix, without having the figures appear in the main toc/figurelist?

Comment: Have you tried packages like `tocloft`?

Comment: You should provide more information

Comment: I would add links from the original to the expanded figure using \pageref and the hyperref package.  Do you want to reuse the figure number, or possibly the entire caption?  (tricky, but possible)

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I've tried an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `minitoc` approach with `\sectlof` as local `List of figures` command.

The appearence of the local `LoF` can be changed with `\mtc...` commands, but there's not much information by the O.P. how to format the LoF.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hints,insection]{minitoc}

\mtcsetdepth{secttoc}{2}
\begin{document}
\dosectlof

\tableofcontents   
\fakelistoftables
\fakelistoffigures
\section{foo}

\subsection{Foo subsection}


\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure in a normal section}
\end{figure}

\appendix
\setcounter{figure}{0} % Perhaps
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
\section{The first appendix section}
\sectlof

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{beeduck}
\caption{A figure in Appendix List of figure}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup :-)